# Secure and protect classes or DLLs in .NET from being used in IronPython

Tags: c#, security, ironpython

I want to use ironpython inside my C# App, but I am afraid that it will cause a security issue, I don't want the end user to use all the available DLLs of my App, instead I want to provide custom classes that user can use in python.

My question is how to secure my dlls from being used in ironpython.
the end user may addReference of the dll, I want to secure most of the classes from being used.

Comment: You shouldn't be thinking in terms of the language that is being used - more in general terms about sand boxing. There are quite a few articles about sandboxing in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to run IronPython in its own AppDomain and only provide the assemblies you want the user to be able to call to that AppDomain, and then set the security policy to prevent them from referencing more.